# How to select multiple non-contiguous text lines in browsers

Tags: browser

Is it possible to select multiple lines of text and be able to copy them?

If I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> I expect the previous selection to remain while I add another selection from somewhere, and while I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> I expect the top selection to extend to the bottom and not start over.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> partly works, but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> part is nowhere to be seen.

So is it possible to do?

Comment: In what browser are you trying this? Firefox 17 behaves as you expect, with the caveat that Control-(mouse drag) over table cells apparently selects the whole table.

Comment: `If i hold control i expect previous selection to remain while it add another selection from somewhere and while i hold shift i expect top selection to extend to bottom and not start over.`   Then you are confusing a web browser with Windows Explorer. Just because some programs behave that way does not mean that all programs will. Text usually does not let you select separate chunks like that because there would be no defined way to format it. Do you insert a new-line between the chunks? Do you insert a space? Nothing at all? Most programs only let you select one block of text at a time.

Comment: Web programming questions (JavaScript) are off topic here, if you haven't read our [help/on-topic] yet, please do so. I generalized the question so it'd be a better fit here.

Comment: See also: [Can you set and/or change the user’s text selection in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183401/can-you-set-and-or-change-the-users-text-selection-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Try multi selection add-ons, here is one for Chrome which works as we expect it to:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiline-text-selection/ajbomhojbckleofgngogoecoaefclnol/related?hl=en